# Which is the DRY-est way of organizing taxonomy terms under submenus?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

Given the **Active Sales** view with `3 Displays` each having their own **content type** (of the same name) and **url path**:

- Active sales ( `/active-sales` )
- Announcements ( `/announcements` )
- Portfolio ( `/portfolio` )

each of them having a **vocabulary** (with the same name: eg. Active sales -> Active sales (vocabulary)) and each vocabulary having its own **terms** per se:

- Active sales

  - movable property
  - non-movable property
- Portfolio

  - finished contracts
  - organisational procedures

etc..

I want to organize the **taxonomy terms** as **Submenus** with their own **url-path** having the **dictionary url-path** as parent

- Active sales (parent) url-path: `/active-sales`

  - movable property (child 1 submenu): `/movable-property`
  - non-movable property (child 2 submenu): `/nonmovable-property`

### Which is the DRY-est way of achieving this?

My first thought was to create another **View** called *Submenus* and make an **url-path** for each **dictionary term** and order them in the **Main Menu**.